# Java allows to declare abstract methods in an enum type but it's a final class not abstract class

Tags: java

in java, all `enum` types that we created are final classes that inherits `Enum` class. so why does java allow us to declare an abstract method in our `enum` types ? because an `enum` type is a final class, and java doesn't allow us to declare an abstract method in final classes.

Thanks.

Comment: You could override method for each `enum` element to have it's own implementation

Comment: I know it, but the question is not about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not expected to extend them, but you could certainly implement an abstract method many times:

```
public enum Animal {

    COW {
        public String talk() {
            return "moo";
        }
    },
    FROG {
        public String talk() {
            return "croak";
        }
    };

    public abstract String talk();
}
```